# expected mean sentence duration (probability)

Tags: statistics, means

Say I have the following data:

There is a $0.0036 (0.36\%)$ probability $X$ will get $5$ years in prison if he talks to the police.

There is a $0.0045 (0.45\%)$ probability $X$ will get $3.75$ years in prison if he doesn't talk to the police.

How can I find the expected mean sentence durations $X$ will have to spend in prison? (regardless if he talks to the police or not)

My initial thought was to use $EV = \sum P(X_{i}) X_{i}$, but I get some weird values when I calculate the years this way.

Comment: There isn't enough information, since we don't know the probability that he will talk to the police.  Nor are the other terms clear...say he talks to the police.  Are you saying that there is a $1-.0036$ chance that he gets no jail time at all?  Also, it isn't clear what you might mean by "Expected mean value for a year".

Comment: Sorry, the probability that he will talk to the police is 0.0036. I will edit "risk" to "probability" now

Comment: Well...you say there is a $.0036$ chance that he gets $5$ years in prison if he talks to the police, which is not even remotely the same as saying that the probability that he talks to the police is $.0036$   Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: I didn't say that. I just changed risk to probability.

Comment: I was quoting what you wrote.  I have no idea at all what you intended.  It can't be the case that $.0036$ and $.0045$ represent the probabilities that he does or does not talk to the police, since those two numbers do not add to $1$.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: I don't see why it needs to add to 1 in this case. There's also a probability he can get 10 years, 1 year or even get free. I'm asked specifically to calculate the expected mean sentence duration for said probabilities.

Comment: My final comment:  As I said initially,  there is not nearly enough information given to answer your question.  Your most recent comment proves that, since you casually allude to a whole list of possible outcomes which are obviously relevant but about which we have no information.  I suggest you delete this question until you have all the information needed to solve it.